# Finding proper motor for lead screw lifting?

Tags: motor, torque, rpm

I need to lift amount 0.6 kilogram up to 20 cm in 2 second with Permanent Magnet DC Motor with PWM speed control driver ,for this device:

[image: my device]

So  i have one PM dc motor with 300 RPM MAX,12 V and 2 Watt at max 6 kg.cm Torque which is equal to 0.58 N.m (10.19 kg.cm=1N.m) could check here :

***www.convertunits.com/from/newton+meter/to/kgf+cm***

For this movement use this formula:

(1) **Power (kW) = Torque (N.m) x Speed (RPM) / 9.5488**

So need this torque( moving 600 Gram up to 20 cm in 2 second or  10 (20/2) cm in one second):

***0.6*9.8*0.2/2=0.588 N.m***

The i put in above formula (1) so i have :

***2 watt= 0.588 N.m x Speed (RPM) / 9.5488 => Speed (RPM) =32.4789 RPM***

So which nuts and lead screw are suitable for that movement in 2 second with 32 RPM for 2 second? is there ant table for finding   of The linear motion of the lead screw ?

Dose i have found correct Speed (RPM)?

SO could i use  this motor?:

[12V/24V 0.1W~2W 2rpm~600rpm Gear Motor (Small Geared Electric Dc Motors) for Home Appliance, Electric Curtain,Ticket selling,Monitor cameras](http://www.motors-biz.com/item/1856533/12V-24V-0-1W-2W-2rpm-600rpm-Gear-Motor-Small-Geared-Electric-Dc-Motors-for-Home-Appliance-Electric-Curtain-Ticket-selling-Monitor-cameras.html)

(Speed:300 RPM , Output Power: 0.1W~2W )

So could i use this lead screw whit this Hexagon nuts whit 6 mm diameter and inner diameter is 3mm (guess German small gear screw with 20 turn per Inch):

[image]

SO i use Lead-Screw-Force-Torque-Calculator site with this parameter (my estimations!!!):

[image: Lead-Screw-Force-Torque-Calculator site]

from :  **www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Lead-Screw-Force-Torque-Calculator.phtml**

As you can see i need 0.0783 N.m Torque for going up with 7.87 (20/2.54) turn per cm which leads needs 157.48 (7.87*20) turn to lifting up (20 cm up), So my motor with 2  Watt with speed up to 30 rpm needs to have up to 0.588 N.m or 5.995 kg.cm torque !!!

So dose it correct?

Could i use this site for calculating power of motor needed for linear movement of lead screw and only focus on motor power (watt) and it's RPM by using this site:

***www.racointernational.com/screw_formula.htm***

Thanks a lot.

Comment: it's a duplicated for my question in **http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/11390/finding-proper-motor-for-lead-screw-lifting** site, because of not answering to that question, i have made this in here and deleted old post in **robotics.stackexchange** ( maybe here is right place to ask ).

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using calculators on sites is you never know whether to trust them. 9.5488? Where does that magic number come from? Fortunately, doing this sort of calculation from first principles is straightforward, and once you've done it, you know you can trust the result. Incidentally, racointernational asks you for your guess of the efficiency, so you still need to input your own guesses!

Your specification for the load is 600g force, about 6N force, to move through 0.2m in 2 seconds.

The power at the load is therefore 6N x 0.1m/s = 0.6 watts.

If you use an 'ordinary' screw thread without lubrication, then you can assume an efficiency of no more than 25%. With special thread forms (ie using what's called a 'leadscrew' rather than a 'screw') and lubrication, you can get higher efficiencies. Let's stick with the worst case for the moment and assume 25%.

The motor power must therefore be at least 0.6W/25% = 2.4W, less with lubrication.

A screw has a simple parameter 'pitch', which is the distance a nut moves for one full turn. This allows a conversion between turns and linear motion. I tend to remember that M6 has one turn per mm, other diameters of screw have a more or less proportional pitch, which I can look up if I need it exactly.

If we want to travel at 0.1m/s, then we need 100 pitches of 1mm per second, or 100 turns per second, or 6000 rpm, or 200pi radians per second. That last unit might seem a bit odd, but there are very good reasons for measuring rotation in radians.

As we know the motor has a power output of 2.4W, we can work out the torque as 2.4/200pi = 3.8mNm if we want to (as work (Joules) done by a torque  (Nm) is just the torque times the number of radians turned through). However, speed and power completely define a motor, so we can pick motors by those, without having to grub around in the torque figures unnecessarily.

So you can meet your specification with a 2.4W 6000rpm motor, with a standard M6 1mm pitch thread. Or 12000rpm with a 3mm thread. Or 3000rpm with a 12mm thread. If you pay more for a leadscrew, then perhaps a lower power. You choose.

(edit) it's just occured to me that 9.549 is 60/2pi, the rpm to radian/s second conversion factor. Much nicer to know where it comes from isn't it? I usually approximate that factor to 10. The difference between 9.55 and 10 is nothing compared to the uncertainty in 'is the efficiency 25% or 50%?' (/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Lifting 600 grams a distance of 20 cm requires an energy of mgh (mass x gravitational constant x height) = 0.6 x 0.2 x 9.81 = 1.177 joules. Given you want this executed in 2 seconds, the average power is 0.5886 watts. Take into account frictional losses yourself but this could easily be the limiting factor of 2 watts for your motor.

I'm not going to comment on this site or that site for the lead screw calculator because it seems inappropriate for EE.