# How to detect type of my DC motor?

Tags: motor, dc, device-characteristics

According to [my last question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/280762/finding-proper-motor-for-lead-screw-lifting/280790#280790) (summery for lifting one 0.6Kg load across one m1 lead screw up to 20cm at 2 Second), I found one motor in my stock ware so it's type is :

RS-540SH 00536725

[image]

SO when i test it with this circuit (with one Auto transformer) :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWl8wU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

we have 4A in ac Ampere meter and  12V in no load a the DC motor Wires,So i could not find which type of RS-540SH-... this is in google i found some tables like this :

[image: Rs540SH table]

So have could find this motor characteristics,Do i need to test the motor manually and find it's characteristics?

I guess this motor is used in hairdryer, could i test this motor by routine hairdryer DC motor power Supply Circuit similar to this ( we avoiding to use reducer transformer because of it's large space and lack of space in our device !!):

[image: hairdryer DC motor power Supply Circuit]

So is there need any zener diode in motor wires for avoiding for high voltage to this kind motor (if yes what type).

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can match motor by f/V ratio (kRPM/V) and DCR or locked rotor current (stall current)  The ratio of Stall torque to rated torque also gives the ESR and also the start to rated current ratio.

No need for Zener transient protection to motor with caps but the series bridge PIV must withstand the spike. Generally line filters attenuate this very well.